# Linkedin LeadNotification API

Tags: linkedin-api

Linkedin Leadnotification endpoint is throwing 500 internal server Error. I couldn't able to find the root cause for it. I gave right permission to access this endpoint.
Provided my curl request for troubleshooting

curl --location 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/leadNotifications' 
--header 'LinkedIn-Version: 202402' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer some-access-token' \

--data '{"webhook": "webhook_url","owner": {"sponsoredAccount": "urn:li:sponsoredAccount:508222354"}, "leadType": "SPONSORED"}'

I tried to create webhook subscription for linkedin